# How do I have a identity number as parameter for each instance of a same service, on service fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Hi I have a stateless service which I will be hosting on service fabric with 5 nodes , my service will be having 5 instance running and getting records from same table in a database. So now I want to pass a parameter for each instance like for instance 1 as 1 , 2 as 2 etc so that each instance can fetch only those records from table matching to a column (InstanceId) in table, fetching records from a table I will use this parameter in where clause for different instances. How can I achieve this ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution could be a service-coordinator that could have a pool of ids.
That service could know when a new instance of the service that fetches data from db is created and give it an id from the pool.
If instance of the service that fetches data goes down (you can track it in OnAbort or OnClose), that instance returns its id to the pool.

> how can I get to know when a new instance of the service is created

When a service is instantiated, in its code you can override different events.
You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-advanced-usage), Stateless service instance lifecycle paragraph.
For example, in `OnOpenAsync` or in the beginning of `RunAsyc` you can ask other services for personal, unique id.

> And this OnAbort or OnClose are the events available in SF?

These events are available in each service. When a service goes down, SF will automatically call one of them. So you can call any other service to notify that you want to return an id that is no longer needed.

By the way, I figured out some additional nice things to do:

1. When instance of a service go down, you can send a message through **Service Bus** that an instance with some specific id is no longer available. On the other side of the bus there could be a service with pool of ids that will catch that message and return id to the pool.
2. You can use mechanism of leases from Azure Blob Storage. Initial info could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/lease-blob). The idea is when that you have a class that tries to acquire a lease with some id (in range 1-5). If lease is successfully acquired, it just needs to renew it time to time. If not, you can try another id. The main nice thing here is that you can set a time period after which lease will be free again. So if a service instance goes down, you won't have to “release” its id.

Comment: Hi cassandrad, Exactly I want to do something like this, but in SF how could we achieve that? Like for example how can I get to know when a new instance of the service is created? Is there any event fired in SF at that point of time? And this OnAbort or OnClose are the events available in SF? Can you please give an example or share some links where they have given some examples. I searched for the same but was unable to get it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AjeetKulkarni added details.

Answer (score 0):

In your Stateless service you can access the context of that service, in the case of stateless it is an instance of type `StatelessServiceContext`. The context has a propery `InstanceId` that gives you a unique identifier for that instance.

```
public void SomeServiceMethod()
{
    var instanceId = this.Context.InstanceId;
    // call db with this
}
```

The instance id is going to be a long and it is a sequential id. Beware though, if SF recreates your node(s) or service instances you will likely not get the same instance ids on the new instances.

**Edit**

Another option that may support you better is to use the NodeInstanceId as identifier. It is a `System.Numerics.BigInteger` that could potentially be a very large number. You should probably do som kind of hash or modulus to get something that is usable in the range you are thinking of (1-5).

```
this.Context.NodeContext.NodeId;
```

But again, this may be a problem if a node is recreated, in which case it gets a new instance id.

Third option could be to look at the actual name of the node:

```
this.Context.NodeContext.NodeName
```

and parse the node number from that since the naming of the nodes will be `_{node type name}_{count}_`, so if you have a node type called `backend` you will have `_backend_0_`, `_backend_1_`, `_backend_2_` and so on. The problem might be in the scenario where one node becomes unresponsive and SF creates a new and takes the broken one out of the scaleset, during this period you may actually have 6 nodes (but 5 only active).